# regex for only contain numbers in xslt

Tags: regex, xml, xslt

I want to select `td` element which contains only numbers in XSLT.

Input:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>AWS</td>
    <td>1234</td>
    <td>ED123</td>
    <td>874</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Tried XPath:

```
table/tr/td[not(matches(.,['a-zA-Z']))]
```

As the results `td[2]` and `td[4]` should be selected.

I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: Where is the code you're having problems with?

Comment: `td[2]` contains a space in addition to digits.

Comment: @michael.hor257k it is my fault...I will update the quection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression places the square brackets outside the regex pattern. It should be:

```
table/tr/td[not(matches(.,'[a-zA-Z]'))]
```

---

However, this does NOT *"select `td` element which contains only numbers"*. It selects `td` elements which do not contain ASCII characters in the range from a to z and in the range from A to Z. There are many other characters that are not "numbers".

If your purpose is to select nodes that contain only **digits**, try:

```
table/tr/td[matches(., '^\d+$')]
```

or:

```
table/tr/td[matches(., '^\d*$')]
```

to include empty nodes.

Answer (score 1):

```
//td[matches(.,'^\s*\d+\s*$')]
```

this will tolerate whitespace around numbers, as is the case with your input.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that would also work in XSLT/XPath 1.0 is to use [`number()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-number) to convert the value to a number.

If a value can't be converted to a number, it's converted to `NaN` (Not a Number).

```
//td[not(string(number(.))='NaN')]
```